# Implement heartbeat for api gateway websockets

Tags: node.js, websocket, aws-api-gateway

I am building a chatroom app using nodejs + api gateway websockets. I understand that each websocket connection can only be idle for up to 29 seconds before it gets disconnected so I wrote a "hearbeat" function where the websocket connection pings the client every 20 seconds to keep the connection alive and not idle and I have the server send a response. Despite my heartbeat function, my websocket connections are still automatically closing every 29 seconds. Can someone let me know what about my implementation is incorrect?

```
Client:

   const ws = new WebSocket(myWebsocketURL);

    ws.onopen = () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        ws.send("ping");
      }, 20000);
    };

    ws.onclose = () => {
      // handle close
    };

Server:

   const api = new ApiGatewayManagementApi({
      endpoint: 'my-apigateway-websocket-url',
    });

    const params = {
      ConnectionId: connectionId,
      Data: Buffer.from('pong'),
    };

    await api.postToConnection(params).promise()
```

Comment: The code you show sends ONE "ping" message 20 seconds after the connection was opened.  After that, it doesn't send any more.

Comment: @jfriend00 OHHH yes that's true. not sure why i didn't realize that before. Thank you!

Comment: 29 seconds timeout is for api integration response timeout and not ws client connection timeout. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/customize-integration-timeouts-in-amazon-api-gateway/